# Defining a probability space for a simple card experiment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I'd like to proof-check my reasoning below.

Consider the following experiment: "draw cards from a deck (with $52$ cards), with replacements, until a king comes out, and then register how many draws were needed."

I want to give a probability space $(\Omega,{\cal A},\Bbb P)$ to model this experiment. This is supposed to be very simple, since random variables are mentioned only in the next chapter of the book.

Since the sample space $\Omega$ must contain all the possible results of the experiment, which are the number of draws, I'd take $\Omega=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, and since $\Omega$ is countable, we put ${\cal A}=\wp(\Omega)$ (that is, every event is a random event).

I guess that $A_n$ = "the first king is drawn at the $n$th step" would be just  $A_n=\{n\}$, and it suffices to define  $\Bbb P$ at these atoms: $$\Bbb P(\{n\}) = \left(\frac{48}{52}\right)^{n-1}\frac{4}{52}=\frac{12^{n-1}}{13^n}. $$

I would like to know if I am missing anything subtle here. It seems that this can be studied using a sample space of sequences of cards and a certain random variable, but as I mentioned above, I'd like to avoid these tools for now and focus on the *mathematical* formalism of this model. Thanks.

Comment: Your $\mathbb P(\{n\})$ calculation is wrong (assuming there is no replacement at each step; otherwise it's okay), but other than that, seems good.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Why is the calculation wrong? Since the process halts when the first king is drawn, we'd multiply the probabilities of not drawing any king in the first  $n-1$ steps, and1the probability of drawing a king in the $n$th step. What did I miss?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry! I forgot to write the crucial information that replacements are allowed. So it's all ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability space you defined is indeed a probability space and is one model of the situation. You could also define it in a slightly different way:

Let $\Omega=\{\text{all permutations of the cards}\}$ and let $\mathcal F=p(\Omega)$. You have a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$. Define a random variable $X: \Omega \to \Bbb R$ where $\Bbb R$ is endowed with the probability measure you said. Pullback that measure through $X$ to get a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$. So you have a measure on on the permutations of the cards.

Either way is fine but I think this way (in my opinion) might capture what's going on a little better.

**Edit** I didn't actually look at your measure and just assumed the calculation was right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just to confirm... when you say to consider my probability measure in $\Bbb R$, do you mean  $\Bbb P (\{x\}) = 12^{x-1}/13^x$ in general?

Comment: This is definitely 'better' in the sense that one can ask more questions about the experiment. In the opening question, events are only of the form 'The first king is drawn in steps $2$, $35$ or $58$'. This formulation allows for more events, like 'The first king drawn is of hearts' or 'The first king drawn follows an ace'.

Comment: Yes, I agree! But for purposes of the exercise, I think my silly model is okay (I decided to learn probability from zero, this is one of the first exercises in chapter one, bear with me haha)

Comment: @IvoTerek I meant just lifting the measure from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R$. I.e. $P(\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb N)=0$.

Comment: No worries -- your model is perfectly fine, the mathematical formalisation is good.

Comment: Ah. In hindsight, my doubt there ended up being a bit dumb, of course. I think it's all clear now, thanks again!

Comment: @IvoTerek No worries, your model is fine. I'm glad to hear you're learning probability.